# SQLite JOIN table with relation

Tags: java, database, sqlite, intellij-idea, relational-database

I am trying to figure out where do I have a problem in this piece of code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:STUDENTS.db");
    Statement stat = conn.createStatement();
    //ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("select * from tabulka_faktov");
    ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery("SELECT tabulka_faktov.MENO, tabulka_faktov.PREDMET1, tabulka_faktov.PREDMET2 FROM tabulka_faktov " +
            "INNER JOIN meno_ID ON tabulka_faktov.MENO = meno_ID.MENO");
    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getString("MENO"));
        System.out.println("predmet 1 = " + rs.getString("PREDMET1"));
        System.out.println("predmet 2 = " + rs.getString("PREDMET2"));
        //System.out.println("volitelny = " + rs.getString("VOLITELNY_PREDMET"));
    }
    rs.close();
    conn.close();
}
```

It doesn't return me an error but I get nothing from this code, just Process finished with exit code 0.

My DB looks like this
[image: DB Design]

I am using SQLite database

Can you guys tell me where do I have an error?

Thanks

Comment: Your arrows don't seem to point at the actual connecting keys. I find it hard to believe that you'll succeed in comparing an integer with a text field (MENO_ID.MENO).

Comment: I was having in mind total replacing of tabulka_faktov.MENO with meno_id.MENO

Answer (score 0):

Change "rs.getString()" into "rs.getNString()"